# Treeview node expanded event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I am working on a treeview control in a update panel. The node is not expanding/collapsing until i click on it twice.

Code Sample :

```
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:TreeView ID="treeGroup" Runat="server" ShowCheckBoxes="All" Font-Underline ="true"  ForeColor="#3376af" Font-Size="Small" ExpandDepth="0"  SelectAction="Expand" PopulateOnDemand ="true" ShowExpandCollapse="False" ontreenodeexpanded="treeGroup_TreeNodeExpanded"></asp:TreeView>
</ContentTemplate>           
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

C# Code Sample :

```
protected void treeGroup_TreeNodeExpanded(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
//Necessary Code
}
```

Can someone please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.treenodeexpanded%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> If the **SelectAction** property for a node is set to
>   **TreeNodeSelectAction.Expand** or **TreeNodeSelectAction.SelectExpand**, the
>   TreeNodeExpanded event is also raised when that node is clicked in the
>   TreeView control.

Comment: Yes.. but can you please help me track what is the issue.

Comment: @ASTEROID could you post the code where you assign properties of each node of the TreeView

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the update panel was the cause of the two click problem. Just remove it and it should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue as well.
Setting the `TreeNodeSelectAction.SelectExpand` still did not fire my `TreeView` function on jQuery until clicked twice.

My issue was resolved when I assigned a change event to the function call of `TreeView` on jQuery side. My `TreeView` is inside the update panel too.

```
function OnTreeViewClick(src) {
$('[id*=' + src.id +'] input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
```